# oracle function in sql developer

Tags: oracle11g

```
create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_TABLE return t_nested_table as
  v_ret   t_nested_table;
begin
  v_ret  := t_nested_table();

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(1, 'one');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(2, 'two');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(3, 'three');

  return v_ret;
end return_table;
```

compilation analysis terminiated

Comment: Um, can you ask a question, please

Comment: What is the definition of `t_nested_table` and `t_col`?  What is the error?

Comment: when i am trying to execute this function its getting compilation analysis terminated and t_nested_table must be declared error

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define types for your `t_nested_table` and `t_col` types, e.g.:

```
create or replace type t_col as object
(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR2(20 byte)
);
/
create or replace type t_nested_table as table of t_col;
/
create or replace FUNCTION RETURN_TABLE return t_nested_table as
  v_ret   t_nested_table;
begin
  v_ret  := t_nested_table();

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(1, 'one');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(2, 'two');

  v_ret.extend;
  v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_col(3, 'three');

  return v_ret;
end return_table;
/
```

You can invoke the function like so:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RETURN_TABLE());
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68c98/2)